# Small size for the Calendar control

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [**Angular Xeditable table**](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) directive.I need to use calendar on it and it works fine when I use the below mentioned code.The problem is the calendar control is very big.Can you tell me how to small it ?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
     <tr style="font-weight: bold">
         <td style="width:30%">@L("VmDateReceived")</td>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="vendor in vm.vendorDetails">
         <td>
          <span editable-bsdate="vendor.dateReceived" e-uib-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" e-ng-click="opened = !opened" e-is-open="opened" e-name="dateReceived" e-form="vendorInformationForm">
           {{ vendor.dateReceived | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' }}
                 </span>
         </td>
     </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: you'll probably need to control with custom css it seems. Perhaps `div[ng-controller] table tr td` and `div[ng-controller] table tr td btn-sm` based on your needs.